# Set JPEG compression for image.save()

Tags: python, rendering, baking

I'd like to know how to set the compression ratio for jpg's for a python script, that is baking ambient occlusion for me. I use the `image.save()` method of the baked image in the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The settings you are looking for are the scene's render settings. When you save an image it will by default use these settings as well. The quality (JPEG compression) parameter is under the scene's render image settings:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.quality
```

However, an Image data object's normal save function ( `bpy.data.images['MyImage'].save()` ) will not use the scene's render settings. It uses the image format settings which relates to the image saving dialogue opened through the UV/Image Editor's UI.

So to save and take the render settings into account use the Image data object's `save_render` function:

```
img = bpy.data.images['MyImage']
img.save_render( filepath = img.filepath, scene = bpy.context.scene )
```

The `filepath = img.filepath` bit makes sure you save on the image's existing file path. The `scene = bpy.context.scene` makes sure you save with the current scene's render settings applied, including the compression or quality parameter.

Comment: Thx, i thought of it as normal rendering as well. If i apply this quality parameter before save ( `bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.quality = 98; imgae.save();` ), it doesn't apply to the exported jpg. Is there something else i should think of?

Comment: That's odd, looking into it.

Comment: could you reproduce/reconstruct the case?

Comment: I could reproduce the case, still looking. Meanwhile you can try to implement a different solution by loading the baked image to the compositor and rendering it out to file. This way the render settings determine the quality and all other image properties: https://github.com/Tlousky/production_scripts/blob/master/batch_converter.py

Comment: @Thronella, I updated the answer and found an easy solution.

Comment: For newer visitors: `image.save(...)` now accepts `quality` for jpeg-like formats - `image.save(quality=100)`